# Extracting strings and writing to a new file

Tags: vbscript, scripting, wsh

I was googling around but didn't find the right answer, perhaps people from here are willingly and able to help me. 
I'm very new to VBS or WSH and I like to have a solution for this problem:

I'm searching for textstrings within a file **without a line break** (only one line). The textstrings I'm looking for start always with the same content "jpgline" and ends with the three letters "qbm". How can we extract each sentence (the strings are always 64 chars long) containg "*jpgline....qbm*" into a separate file.

I'm looking for a solution in Visual Basic Script as I use Windows 7.

Thanks in advance

M i k e

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^jpgline.*qbm$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt")
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\output.txt", 2, True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  If re.Test(line) Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

I'm WONDERING ABOUT THIS LINE

 If re.Test(line) Then outFile.WriteLine line

What is Test ??

Comment: `re`, as you can see, is the regular expression object created earlier. [`Test`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32x2hy1) is a method of this object that checks if its argument (in this case the variable `line`) matches the regex pattern (here: `^jpgline.*qbm$`, i.e. a string that begins with "jpgline" and ends with "qbm").

Comment: How *exactly* did it "not work" for you, BTW? It would be quite helpful if you were a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As your input file has no lines, use .ReadAll() to load its entire content into a string variable. Apply a RegExp to get all parts (Matches) defined by the pattern "jpgline.{N}qbm" where N is either 64 or 64 - the length of the pre/suffix. Ansgar has shown how to open and write to the output file.

Use the [RegExp Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to learn about .Execute and how to loop over the resulting match collection. The docs will tell you about .Test too.

Comment: Hi, I was looking in the library but found only one useful script, but it doesn't work:

Comment: Hi Ansgar,
using this Pattern **"jpgline\w{1,64}\.qbm"** I only get 11 of 28 results, the first 17 results were ignored. objRegEx. Global ist still True and "Input.txt" has still no CrLf (hex 0D0A). What is wrong ?

Comment: @user2648359 Update your question with the code you currently have, and also provide an example for input and desired output.